# How to open a url in chrome from app having deep linking

Tags: android, android-webview, deep-linking

The main theme of my app is to open a website from my app into the chrome engine when user clicks on the button in the app. When i have implemented the code for click event it working fine, but  when i have implemented the deep linking for my app, these was an that issue i'm facing.

[image]

**My App is showing some thing like this when i click on the button. Instead of this when user clicks on the button the website has to launch in chrome engine.**

The MainActivity file of my app look like:-

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    intent = getIntent();
    action = intent.getAction();
    uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/")));
    }
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/")));
        }
    });
}
```

The Mainefest file of my app look like:-

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="stackoverflow.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code in the button click event, by **setting package name of the chrome** to the intent, and working fine as per my requirement.

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent1.setData(Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com/"));
            intent1.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
            startActivity(intent1);
```